# C++ binary search struggle

Tags: c++, binary-search

Sorry for using polish names but I started with them and didin't want to confuse myself. I've got an assignment to find the possible answer to this equation `x^3 + px = q`, without negative numbers. Also I Have to use binary searching for that, it seemed to me pretty easy at first but I keep on getting wrong outputs. Just wanted some advice on what I should focus on, not an entire solution.
Cheers!

```
int main() {
int p, q, x;
cin >> p >> q;
int tablica[q-1];
for(int i = q-1; i>=0; i--){
    tablica[i] = q;
    q--;
}
bool znalezione = false;
int poczatek = 0;
int koniec = q-1;


while(!znalezione){
    int srodek = (poczatek + koniec)/2;
    tablica[srodek] = x;
    if(x*x*x + p*x == q){
        znalezione = true;
    }
    else
        if(x*x*x + p*x > q){
            koniec = srodek -1;
        }
        else
            poczatek = srodek +1;
}
cout << x;
```

}

Comment: There are a lot of problems here. For example, `x` is never initialized. Perhaps you wanted to use `srodek` as `x`. What is `tablica`? Assigned to, but never read. Is it always the case that the solution is between `0` and `q-1`? Why `int`? This equation can have non-integer solutions.

Comment: I don't see how that could possibly terminate, or what the purpose of the table is.

Comment: Also, you read `p` and never use it; and the first thing you do in the first loop is to write outside the array.

Comment: I suspect that the point of this exercise is discovering that you don’t need an array, or any kind of container, to do binary search.

Comment: You would probably benefit from focusing on smaller pieces, making sure they work correctly. Step through the code -- either with a debugger or by hand -- and make sure each piece does what you want it to do. At each stage, do the variables have the values you expect?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to find the value of `x`. The first thing that I notice is that `x` is not initialized and then in the line `tablica[srodek] = x`, you are assigning this to array, this will give a garbage value in `tablica`.

Additionally, you are never updating the value of `x`. It will always display the value which was at the beginning (garbage value in your case)

Answer (score 0):

`int tablica[q-1];` is not standard c++, use `std::vector`. I'm not sure why you even need a table. You've got the general idea but  you never assigned anything to `x`. Binary search algorithm is something like this:

```
std::optional<int> binary_search(int begin, int end, int element)
{
    while(end-begin>0)
    {
        int midPoint = (end+begin)/2;
        if(midPoint ==element)
            return midPoint;
        else if (midPoint > element)
            begin = midPoint+1;
        else
            end = midPoint-1;
    }
    return {};
}
```

So all you have to do is replace insides of those `if` statements with your equation.